# How to extract languages data nested in the api resonse using react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, database, api

I am tring to extract a piece of information that is nested in the api. However, when I do so, it gives me an error. I have already tried using the index for example {this.state.country.languages[0].iso639_1} etc... If anyone knows, please let me know. Thanks!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CountryItem from "../components/CountryItem";
import axios from "axios";


class CountryPage extends React.Component{

    state = {
        country: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${this.props.match.params.name}`)
            .then(response=> {
                this.setState({
                    country: response.data[0]
                })
                console.log(this.state.country)
            })
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Country: {this.props.match.params.name}</h1>
                <div>Native Name: {this.state.country.nativeName}</div>
                <div>Demograph: {this.state.country.demonym}</div>
                <div>Population: {this.state.country.population}</div>
                <div>Region: {this.state.country.region}</div>
                <div>Subregion: {this.state.country.subregion}</div>
                <div>Timezones: {this.state.country.timezones}</div>
        <div>Langauges: {this.state.country.languages[0].iso639_1}</div>
                <div>Capitol: {this.state.country.capital}</div>
                <div>Calling Code: {this.state.country.callingCodes}</div>
                <div>Area :{this.state.country.area}</div>
                <div>Country Code: {this.state.country.alpha3Code}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CountryPage;



 [{"name":"China","topLevelDomain":[".cn"],"alpha2Code":"CN","alpha3Code":"CHN","callingCodes":["86"],"capital":"Beijing","altSpellings":["CN","Zhōngguó","Zhongguo","Zhonghua","People's Republic of China","中华人民共和国","Zhōnghuá Rénmín Gònghéguó"],"region":"Asia","subregion":"Eastern Asia","population":1377422166,"latlng":[35.0,105.0],"demonym":"Chinese","area":9640011.0,"gini":47.0,"timezones":["UTC+08:00"],"borders":["AFG","BTN","MMR","HKG","IND","KAZ","PRK","KGZ","LAO","MAC","MNG","PAK","RUS","TJK","VNM"],"nativeName":"中国","numericCode":"156","currencies":[{"code":"CNY","name":"Chinese yuan","symbol":"¥"}],"languages":[{"iso639_1":"zh","iso639_2":"zho","name":"Chinese","nativeName":"中文 (Zhōngwén)"}],"translations":{"de":"China","es":"China","fr":"Chine","ja":"中国","it":"Cina","br":"China","pt":"China","nl":"China","hr":"Kina","fa":"چین"},"flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/chn.svg","regionalBlocs":[],"cioc":"CHN"},{"name":"Macao","topLevelDomain":[".mo"],"alpha2Code":"MO","alpha3Code":"MAC","callingCodes":["853"],"capital":"","altSpellings":["MO","澳门","Macao Special Administrative Region of the People's Republic of China","中華人民共和國澳門特別行政區","Região Administrativa Especial de Macau da República Popular da China"],"region":"Asia","subregion":"Eastern Asia","population":649100,"latlng":[22.16666666,113.55],"demonym":"Chinese","area":30.0,"gini":null,"timezones":["UTC+08:00"],"borders":["CHN"],"nativeName":"澳門","numericCode":"446","currencies":[{"code":"MOP","name":"Macanese pataca","symbol":"P"}],"languages":[{"iso639_1":"zh","iso639_2":"zho","name":"Chinese","nativeName":"中文 (Zhōngwén)"},{"iso639_1":"pt","iso639_2":"por","name":"Portuguese","nativeName":"Português"}],"translations":{"de":"Macao","es":"Macao","fr":"Macao","ja":"マカオ","it":"Macao","br":"Macau","pt":"Macau","nl":"Macao","hr":"Makao","fa":"مکائو"},"flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/mac.svg","regionalBlocs":[],"cioc":""},{"name":"Taiwan","topLevelDomain":[".tw"],"alpha2Code":"TW","alpha3Code":"TWN","callingCodes":["886"],"capital":"Taipei","altSpellings":["TW","Táiwān","Republic of China","中華民國","Zhōnghuá Mínguó"],"region":"Asia","subregion":"Eastern Asia","population":23503349,"latlng":[23.5,121.0],"demonym":"Taiwanese","area":36193.0,"gini":null,"timezones":["UTC+08:00"],"borders":[],"nativeName":"臺灣","numericCode":"158","currencies":[{"code":"TWD","name":"New Taiwan dollar","symbol":"$"}],"languages":[{"iso639_1":"zh","iso639_2":"zho","name":"Chinese","nativeName":"中文 (Zhōngwén)"}],"translations":{"de":"Taiwan","es":"Taiwán","fr":"Taïwan","ja":"台湾（中華民国）","it":"Taiwan","br":"Taiwan","pt":"Taiwan","nl":"Taiwan","hr":"Tajvan","fa":"تایوان"},"flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/twn.svg","regionalBlocs":[],"cioc":"TPE"}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to share your code. This looks like a classic case of trying to access a variable before an asynchronous process finished.

Comment: Hey, thanks for telling me. I forgot to include it. I just included it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Languages is an array, so you would access it like so:

```
this.state.country.languages[0]
```

And then select the value that you need from object like so:

```
this.state.country.languages[0].iso639_1
```

EDIT:

Change initial `country` state to be `null` instead of an empty array and
before the `return` in your `render()` method paste this if

```
if(!this.state.country){
   return <p>Loading</p>
}
```

Comment: Can you copy paste whole response body here?

Comment: Yes, I have just included it in the post

Comment: It seems that you have a different error, i managed to access the languages object as described. Can you paste the error?

Comment: Hm, thats weird. Can you also paste you state object after response? And code snippet of how you are setting your state.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! This worked. But I dont understand why

Comment: As the guy that replied to you stated - you were trying to access object that wasn't there yet. The response hasn't came back before trying to use it. If this suits your needs - please accept as answered. :) The other properties did not throw an error becouse you were trying to access the properties of array object, so you just got undefined, but since `language` was undefined by itself you could not access any properties of that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: when your screen is mounted your `state.country.languages` is undefined, so whenever you try to access an index or property of that you will get an error.
You can either:

1. Initialize state with mock values:

```js
  state = {
    country: {
      languages:[]
    }
  }
```

2. As Mantas Giniūnas suggested, make a conditional:

```html
...
  <div>Langauges: {this.state.country.languages ? this.state.country.languages[0].iso639_1 : ''}</div>
...
```